# API SCORM with flash actionscript 3 in moodle?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4, scorm1.2

I want to create template in flash using actionscript 3, this template will call .swf as screens which are also topics?

I need to put the actionscript code which communicate with API in swf, and I need that to let moodle track the .swf which is as screens or topics from flash.

Is it possible? I am just trying to generate html from flash with scorm 1.2. The moodle just tracks the html page that contains the script, but if I have links in swf that call another swf then moodle don't track it?
How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do SCORM with Flash is to have your HTML container do the API discovery, and then use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call out to JS for API calls (either directly or through a set of functions you define).

Comment: i have flash player and i want from this flash to call .swf, so its not possible to track these .swf that called from flash player?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your question here.  The best way to do this is for your master SWF or your loaded SWFs (slides, quizzes, etc) to use ExternalInterface to make calls to Javascript in your container HTML page to make the SCORM tracking calls.

Comment: ok, thank u , now i really understand ExternalInterface , but the question how to track element in scorm, about lesson i used cmi.core.lesson_status but i need to track the element also in swf as what i explain if i am have one html that call swf and this swf load another swf how i can tracked that the user open the second swf

Comment: This really depends on your situation and how your course is structured.  It sounds like you want to set a bookmark, or track other progress other than completion.  cmi.core.lesson_location and/or cmi.suspend_data can be used for this.  What you store in these is up to you (SCROM 1.2 defines that these exist, but not the data values).

Comment: logically the value of cmi.core.lesson_location indicate where the learner reach page1 or page 5 as index of pages but about suspend_data i am try to save the pages ids which learner has visited as page1,page2,page3.... so is it right?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  I normally use suspend_data to store the state of the module, so that when the student returns, it behaves the same was as if they didn't quit.

Comment: ok, thank u very much, i wanna to ask u question about function with scorm 1.2, i am publish html with scorm 1.2 from flash , my problem in lesson _status, so when th student 1st time visit the course and exist from the course ,the status will be incomplete and the 2nd time open the html the status will be complete and i try to set it as incomplete but doesn't work i think the problem in function scorm Initalize i am traced the function but there is no command to let the status to be complete, can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out pipwerks ActionScript SCORM Classes http://pipwerks.com/downloads/

Comment: Mike i don't want to use function from pipwerks to communicate with scorm